# How can it be possible that I hear people voice from my computer speaker?

Tags: filters, frequency-spectrum, noise, digital-filters, interference

I searched on web and apparently can be due to truck drivers communicating at CB band which is around 20MHz. And apparently this communication may interference with the frequencies used by computer's audio card.

How is this electronically and physically possible that these MHz communications are able to interfere exiting from my laptop speaker? What is the explanation for this signal interference effect? What is due to.

Is there something that will more likely to cause this interference? I mean, can this happen with every RF transmitted by anyone because they just need to be strong... or there are conditions (I don't know: transmitted carrier frequency signal, shape of signal, nonfilteringinTX, etc etc) that can increase probability to create interferences?

Comment: I have no idea how out-of-band digital communications can sound like anything other than horrible digital noise.  But AM and FM radio can sometimes come into a speaker's amplifier circuit and, because of non-linearities in that amplifier/speaker circuit, can come out.  Especially if you're located very close to a strong broadcast transmitter.

Comment: Cable length is also a factor, with longer cables more likely to pick up enough power to create this interference.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson My high school math classroom was on the same electrical circuit as one of the local radio stations. If I switched my hearing aids to "loop coil" (induction coil, rather than microphone), I could listen to music all class. :-)

Comment: This exact same question has been asked in Electronics.SE too and has an answer there.